# Rsync forward name lookup

Tags: rsync

I'm getting this error:

```
journalctl | grep rsync

Jan 26 00:52:08 rene-desktop rsyncd[1699]: forward name lookup for odroidxu4-backup failed: Name or service not known



sudo nano rsyncd.conf
port = 872
[Nextcloud]
path = /media/./Nextcloud/
uid = root
gid = users
list = yes
read only = yes
write only = no
use chroot = yes
hosts allow = 192.168.1.189,odroidxu4-backup
auth users = rene
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
lock file = /var/lock/rsyncd-Nextcloud
```

I don't understand I get the error when I typed it into host allow in rsyncd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the OS can't resolve the hostname odroidxu4-backup.

Try specifying it by IP address, adding its name and IP to the `hosts` file or otherwise changing DNS so it can resolve.

Note: if its IP is 192.168.1.189, you don't need to specify the name in the `rsyncd.conf` – just use the IP address. 
This will be faster as well, I expect.